# active button should not change color on hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have separately set the hover and active function wherein the color will change when when i hover over menus in navigation

```css
/* Change the color of links on hover */
nav .nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: peachpuff;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.active {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  color: snow;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#Fashion">Fashion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#StyleHunter">StyleHunter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Lifestyle">Lifestyle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Celebrity">Celebrity</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Videos">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Interviews">Interviews</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

bar and also  the color is changed for the menu which is set to active. But again when i am hovering over the active button it's color changes from active to hover. How do i stop this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.nav>li:not(.active)>a:hover {
  background-color: peachpuff;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS code

```
/* Change the color of links on hover */
.nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: peachpuff;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.nav li.active a {
  background-color: darkslategray;
  color: snow;
}
```

i hove it help you

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. but sorry to say it didn't work :(

Comment: @Tathagata it's strange.This works for me in Firefox and Chrome.